# gmaps4rails gem v2.0.4 marker changes position every time the page is refreshed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmaps4rails, rails-geocoder

I apologize in advance if this question is stupid/not being asked correctly, this is my first post in stackoverflow and I'm completely new at RoR...

I have a rails application which uses the *`gem gmaps4rails v2.0.4`*. The application takes in an address (street, city and country), uses *geocoder* to calculate the latitude and longitude then plugs them into my marker builder.

Every time I refresh my show page, the marker in google maps changes position...I even tried to plug in the actual latitude and longitude `([{"lat":49.245253,"lng":-123.0651361}])` instead of "`raw @hash.to_json`" and it still renders the marker in different positions every time I refresh.

does anyone know how to fix this?

Note: I tried to copy and paste that coordinate in google maps as well and the marker is very consistent in its position. My controller.rb and show.html.erb are pasted below. Thanks in advance!!

*controller.rb*

```
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@branches) do |branch, marker|
  marker.lat branch.latitude
  marker.lng branch.longitude
end
```

*show.html.erb*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I feel like im not providing enough information so please, do let me know what I am missing....

Comment: the earth is rotating so is the marker...hehe..sorry just for gags!! :P

Comment: aw man, i wish i took that into consideration before asking ><

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a feature to prevent overlapping. [Its documented in the code here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/gmaps/objects/handler.coffee#L5).

You can customise or remove the behaviour, example:

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { markers: { maxRandomDistance: null } });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!! and keep up the good work with the gem :)